# Recursion with an Array; can't get the right value to return

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, return

**Solution found - in under 5 minutes, thanks folks!**

Clarification:  The contents of my array are the values 0-29.  So array[0][0] = 0, while array[29][0] = 29 --- they're just test values.  Also, I have a potential solution that's been posted multiple times, going to try that.

**Recursive Solution: Not working!**
Explanation: An integer, time, is passed into the function.  It's then used to provide an end to the FOR statement (`counter<time`). The IF section (`time == 0`) provides a base case where the recursion should terminate, returning 0.  The ELSE section is where the recursive call occurs: total is a private variable defined in the header file, elsewhere.  It's initialized to 0 in a constructor, elsewhere.  The function calls itself, recursively, adding `productsAndSales[time-1][0]` to total, again, and again, until the base call.  Then the total is returned, and printed out later.  Well, that's what I hoped for anyway.

What I imagined would happen is that I would add up all the values in this one column of the array and the value would get returned, and printed out.  Instead if returns 0.  If I set the IF section to "return 1", I noticed that it returns powers of 2, for whatever value time is.  EG: Time = 3, it returns 2*2 + 1.  If time = 5, it returns 2*2*2*2 + 1.

I don't understand why it's not returning the value I'm expecting.  One thing I thought of is that I'm attempting to use private variable total in the return section, along with the recursive call...maybe that's a no-no somehow?

```
int CompanySales::calcTotals( int time )
{
  cout << setw( 4 );
  if ( time == 0 )
   {
    return 0;
   }
  else
   {
    return total += calcTotals( productsAndSales[ time-1 ][ 0 ]);
   }
}
```

**Iterative Solution: Working!**
Explanation: An integer, time, is passed into the function.  It's then used to provide an end to the FOR statement (`counter<time`).  The FOR statement cycles through an array, adding all of the values in one column together.  The value is then returned (and elsewhere in the program, printed out).  Works perfectly.

```
int CompanySales::calcTotals( int time )
{
 int total = 0;
 cout << setw( 4 );

 for ( int counter = 0; counter < time; counter++ )
 {
  total += productsAndSales[counter][0];
 }
 return total0;
}
```

Comment: What's with the random `setw` in the functions? You aren't printing anything. Also, there is no `total` in the recursive function. Is that global?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you posted the contents of your productsAndSales array.

Comment: Indeed, unless I'm mistaken you're passing the wrong thing into your recursive call.

Comment: @Gman, sorry, I thought about taking the setw since it's just garbage to you folks - it's part of my formatting as it were.  Still, should've taken taken it out just for the code example here.

Comment: @overslacked - posted them, but they're just test values
@Ron - Well, yes and no, I didn't really write the call in an effective fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the global `total`, make it an argument.

```
int totals = calcTotals(time-1, 0); // Call it starting at the end, 
                                    // so we don't have to pass along the `time`


int CompanySales::calcTotals( int counter, int total )
{
  if ( counter == 0 ) {
    return total;
  }
  else {
    return calcTotals(counter - 1, total + productsAndSales[counter][ 0 ]);
  }
}
```

Now it's tail recursive too.

Comment: Damn, I was kinda thinking that was it...let me try that

Comment: GAH.  Perfect solution.  I had realized I should be passing total as an argument rather than using the global version, but I would've never figured out the way to write the recursive call as well as you did - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in your recursive function you're expecting time as a parameter to your function, but when you make the recursive call, its passing the value of your productsAndSales array, not the (time - 1) that I would have expected.

So assuming that the contents of your productAndSales array does not contain zero, the time == 0 termination check will never occur

Comment: @Steve - well, this was mostly just an initial test for the recursive function.  I should have (and have now) posted the contents of my array, which are just (non-zero) test values.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong argument being passed around:

```
total += calcTotals( productsAndSales[ time-1 ][ 0 ]);
```

Should be:

```
total +=  productsAndSales[ time ][ 0 ]  + calcTotals(time - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
return total += productsAndSales[time - 1][0] + calcTotals(time - 1);
```

Comment: This works as well I believe - didn't test, but looks like a similar answer which worked.

Answer (score 1):

This should produce the same result as the iterative function.

```
int CompanySales::calcTotals( int time )
{
  cout << setw( 4 );
  if ( time == 0 ){
    return 0;
  }
  else{
    return productsAndSales[time-1][ 0 ] + calcTotals( time - 1 );
  }
}
```

Comment: Works, you're the third to post it ;0  Wish I had thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your recursive solution are you actually adding a `productsAndSales` value -- you are passing in those values as the time parameter to your `calcTotals()` function.

So if total starts as zero, you are simply calling this function a number of times and never adding anything other than zero to it.

Comment: They were non-zero values (posted them).

Comment: Right, but you never actually added them -- they were always parameters to another invocation of the `calcTotals()` function.  Eventually you'd get to the point where the time value was zero and then that zero value would percolate back up.

Glad you found a good answer above, though!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be

```
int CompanySales::calcTotals( int time )
{
  int total = 0;
  cout << setw( 4 );
  if ( time == 0 )
   {
    return 0;
   }
  else
   {
    return total += productsAndSales[ time ][ 0 ] + calcTotals( time - 1);
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so - each time you call it, recursively, it'll be setting total to 0.

Comment: No, it won't as the variables are created on a stack with different scope for each call. However the size of the stack may restrict your ability to recurse indefinitely.

Comment: On a different note, your assumption that the state of the variables would persist across calls, leads to a different programming construct called "closures".